# Global Variables and Functions in Headers

Tags: c++, class, header, global-variables, code-separation

I'm trying to separate my code into headers and cpps
I made a .h and .cpp for every class I had
but I have no idea where to put the functions (that aren't in classes) and the global variables
I tried putting them in main but it didn't work
I also tried putting them in every cpp that needed them but I got the error of (Multiple Definition of the variable)
What to do?

Answer (score 2):

In the .h:

```
extern int myGlobal;
int myFunction(int arg);
```

In *one* of the .cpp files:

```
int myGlobal;

int myFunction(int arg)
{
    return arg + 5;
}
```

You can split stuff across multiple .cpp files, just don't *define* anything in more than one place. If you put a definition in a .h file, and include it multiple times, you get multiple (conflicting) definitions.